# Creating a custom function to replace one in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress 3.0 and the 'the_post_thumbnail' function to resize my images. The problem is that the function doesn't resize to exact dimensions when you don't specify a square image.

```
// Works fine
add_image_size('my-image-size',100, 100, true);

// Image is only resized to width or height, not both
add_image_size('my-image-size',265, 182, true);
```

I'm pretty sure this is a bug, as I feel the image should be cropped to both dimensions to make an exact size. I could just edit the 'image_resize_dimensions' function in media.php, but I'm wondering if there is a better way, some way to override that function with my own?

Thanks!

Darren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most of my theme development prior to 3.0 I used the timthumb plugin with much success. As i also found the built-in functions lacking. You can find the info [here](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/).

Comment: Cheers, I've used that plugin in combination with this little gem to just get the URI of the image and then resize it with phpTumb. Simples!

http://www.leewillis.co.uk/getting-url-post-thumbnails-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

[Mark JaQuith has an article](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/new-in-wordpress-2-9-post-thumbnail-images/) recommended by the [Codex page on the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) function.  It discusses using a different function "set_post_thumbnail_size() to change image sizes.

```
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50, true ); 
    // 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall, hard crop mode
```

It has a crop flag argument that you can pass to perform a hard crop to the exact dimensions you specify, or a soft crop, which works the way you are experiencing.  I know the article discusses WP 2.9 specifically, but it might help.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that hard cropping isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can't override functions in PHP. You'll get a fatal error if you attempt to define a function with the same name within the same scope.</s> Apparently you can use this: [override_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) to override built-in functions. Not sure about ones define in other files though.

You could define another function (ie: add_image_size2) however and refactor the code to call that instead, but you'll end up modifying a lot more of the code than you would by just editing the function.

Comment: I know that in WordPress you can add hooks and filters, I'm just wondering if there is something like that for this.